# I don't know how to write formulas for integration, power series, etc. in Math.SE

Tags: support, mathjax

I want to ask questions from calculus but I do not know how to write the formulas; it causes me lots of problems. I do not know to how write power series as there is no option in my keyboard.

Can anybody guide me on how to write integration and power series? I don't know  how to write the big equation of geometry. Can anybody help me, or give me some  idea, so that I can more easily ask questions about calculus?

Comment: Here is a brief tutorial about MathJax, [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Have a look around for Questions (on the main site, Math.SE) about calculus, power series, etc.  If you right-click on a formula, and choose the submenu Show Math as ... TeX Commands, a smallish text popup will show you the exact $\LaTeX$ syntax for that expression (which you can cut, paste, and edit to get your desired effect).

Comment: Click the edit link of a post that contains the formulas and formats  you need to see the source code of the text. Press cancle to cancle the edit. And use the context manue as [hardmath has described](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26757/i-dont-know-how-to-write-formulas-for-integration-power-series-etc-in-math-s#comment106465_26757)

Answer (score 6):

General math formulas require dollar signs around them.  Single for inline and double for displayed (the below are displayed)

`$1+2=3$` renders as:

$1+2=3$

`$$1+2=3$$` renders as:

$$1+2=3$$

---

## If you want integration:

Use `\int` for regular integrals.  It displays as

> $$\int$$

If you want bounds, use `\int_{a}^{b}`.  It displays as

> $$\int_a^b$$

To add stuff inside the integral, I recommend the format `\int_{a}^{b} f(x)~dx`.  It displays as

> $$\int_{a}^{b} f(x)~dx$$

For double, triple, or quadruple integrals, everything above applies and use `\iint,\iiint,\iiiint`, which respectively displays as

> $$\iint,\iiint,\iiiint$$

For a closed line integral, use `\oint`, which displays as

> $$\oint$$

## For a sum,

please use `\sum`, not `\Sigma`.  The difference is shown below:

> $$\text{\sum}:~\sum\qquad\text{\Sigma}:~\Sigma$$

To add bounds, the same procedure from above applies.  For example, use `\sum_{n=1}^{5} n^2` to get

> $$\text{\sum}:~\sum_{n=1}^{5} n^2\qquad\text{\Sigma}:~\Sigma_{n=1}^{5} n^2$$

If one of your bounds happens to be infinity or negative infinity, use `\infty` or `-\infty`.  For example, `\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}` to get

> $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}$$

And use `\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}` to get

> $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$$

Comment: The difference between \sum and \Sigma is not only what is shown in this posting: $$ \sum_{k=0}^n a_k \text{ versus } \Sigma_{k=0}^n a_k $$ The first of these is \sum; the second is \Sigma. The point is that besides the size and shape, there is the issue of positions of subscripts and superscript. $\qquad$

Comment: Note that {curly braces} are needed only when more than one object is to be included. Thus in \sum_{k=0}^n or \sum_{k=0}^\infty one needs the braces in {k=0} but one need not write \sum_{k=0}^{n} or \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}. But \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} is rendered as $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}$ whereas \sum_{k=0}^+\infty appears as $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^+\infty. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy To the second comment, some people get confused as to whether or not something counts as "one object", and since both ways work in that situation, I thought it better to mention the method that always works.

Comment: thanks a lot @ simply beautiful art

Comment: Nice list, @SimplyBeautifulArt  But there's nowhere you've mentioned that the expressions only render in Mathjax when surrounded on each side by a dollar sign (or two).

Comment: @amWhy True.  I kind of assumed the OP knew generally how MathJax work, given his/her main site content, and was only asking about the integral and sum stuff.

Comment: Fair enough; but for others encountering this post, particularly new users who are at Calc II level, I can never hurt to mention it.  My comment mainly was meant as a compliment regarding your helpful post.